# Removing an element from group but keeping "odd/even" state accurate

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

What are I am trying to achieve is fairly easy (I think) but unfortunately I can't get a hold of the solution.

Consider the following HTML syntax:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically all boxes are floating left and that makes room for 2 per line. The first box has a margin-right of 25px so that the 2nd box is pushed to the edge of its container.

When I click the ".close" link I want the element to "hide();" and if the element I clicked is ":even" then the one that will come into place (the odd one) is to become "even" so the margin is applied and vice versa.

Basically it's a dynamic ":nth-child(2n)"... Every 2nd element has to have no margin, and then first one has to have a margin-right of 25px, even if I remove one element from that group.

Hope that makes sense! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEUvN/) uses red/blue backgrounds for clarity

**CSS first:**

```
.redback {
  background-color:red;   
}
.blueback {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

**Now some Javascript**

```
colorBoxes();

$(".box").on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
    colorBoxes();

});

function colorBoxes() {
  $(".box").removeClass('redback blueback');
  $(".box:visible:odd").addClass('redback');
  $(".box:visible:even").addClass('blueback');
}
```

Comment: Man, you're an angel! hahah Thank you very much thats what I was looking for, you saved me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `.even` and `.odd` classes and bind this function:

```
$('.box').click( function() {
    $(this).hide().nextAll(':visible').toggleClass('even odd');
});
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X5eCa/

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child` is a CSS selector, so you should be able to do:

```
div.box:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right:25px
}

div.box:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

...and you can add whatever other styling you need.

Comment: Yes, I know that but that's not what I am trying to achieve. If I remove an element with jQuery for instance, the odd/even (or nth-child(2n)) doesn't apply because the element has been dynamically removed from the dom.

Comment: If you actually _remove_ the element from the DOM this works. If you just hide it with `display:none` or similar, and the selectors count the hidden elements. As you say: this then doesn't work.